# BitLocker: Decrypting a locked drive, not having recovery key or password

Tags: bitlocker, password-recovery

The problem is that I have forgotten my password to unlock my E: drive which contains my important information. Unfortunately I don't have a recovery key. I click on Unlocking a drive and then I click on forgot my password. I shows some information and displays something like:

> Your recovery key can be identified by: 6FABCF77

And on the next page it says:

> Full BitLocker recovery key identification: 6FABCF77-7BDA-47FD-94D0-E990147ECBE7

I searched a lot for the solution. All solutions require password or recovery key or recovery file ... .
Some examples of the links I have read can be found here: [+](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/bitlocker-recovery-key-lost/107a0882-1ce4-4643-a2ca-4f474af51e3e), [+](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/35430-63-type-bitlocker-recovery-full-bitlocker-recovery-identification), [+](http://rorymon.com/blog/index.php/i-lost-my-bitlocker-recovery-key/).

Comment: If you could recover your drive without the password, there wouldn't be much point in having a password, would there?

Comment: Sorry to say this, but @ultrasawblade is absolutely right.. There is a small chance that a local computer forensic center may have the ability to crack bitlocker (supposedly there is an 800$ program to do it).  But that hole may have been patched in an update.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like what the information above is like a thumbprint for a certificate, which is really just a shorthand way of identifying the public key.

Anyway, without the recovery key or password, there is no chance of recovery of your data.

Answer (score 2):

When BitLocker is enabled it has you store the recovery key. Look on your flash drives for it. You will know the correct one as it will be identified by the key you listed.

The dialog would have looked something like the image below and the file name like:

```
BitLocker Recovery Key 6FABCF77-7BDA-47FD-94D0-E990147ECBE7.txt
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the Bitlocker blue screen on my new Surface Pro. I've looked at so many posts and pages to figure out how to find the code. This is where I found my answer: http://m.windowsitpro.com/microsoft-surface/locating-your-microsoft-surface-bitlocker-recovery-key

Basically, it's saved in a cloud under your Microsoft account. Sign into your Microsoft account and go to this page:

https://skydrive.live.com/recoverykey

You'll will find your actual Key ID and abnormally long Recovery Key number.

Wish this was the first info posted in all that reading and all the responses posted that don't help.

Hope this helps